# inserting and getting bulk indexed DB data as json

Tags: javascript, json, indexeddb

I am creating an application to save data locally using IndexexDB. Is there any way to get and insert bulk data from a indexed DB as json.This is what i have done so far

```
var request = store.openCursor();
    request.onsuccess = function(evt) {  
        var cursor = evt.target.result;  
        if (cursor) {  
            alert("id: " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + " ");

            cursor.continue();  
        }  
        else {  
            console.log("No more entries!");  
        }
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the best way. Indexeddb does not have high level api.